# Worklight 5.0.6 Documentation - Open Questions: "WL.FailResponse", "standard response object", "heartbeat in designated cases"

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

We are using WL 5.0.6.1 and we did not find all the information in the docs.

At
http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wrklight/v5r0m6/topic/com.ibm.worklight.help.doc/apiref/r_wl_client_connect.html

- does the onSuccess(??) receive any parameter/object as input? If so what type/JSON structure?
- the onFailure receives a WL.FailResponse input object - is there any type/JSON-Structure definition available?

At:
http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wrklight/v5r0m6/topic/com.ibm.worklight.help.doc/apiref/r_wl_client_invokeprocedure.html

- it says: "the failure handler receives a standard response object." ... is there a type definition for a "standard response object"?

At:
http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wrklight/v5r0m6/topic/com.ibm.worklight.help.doc/apiref/r_wl_client_setheartbeatinterval.html

in the WorkingOffline PDF:  http://public.dhe.ibm.com/software/mobile-solutions/worklight/docs/v600/05_04_Working_offline.pdf it says: " Both WL.Events.WORKLIGHT_IS_CONNECTED and 
WL.Events.WORKLIGHT_IS_DISCONNECTED events can be fired 
by heartbeat in designated cases"

- What are these "designated cases"?

  - when the heartbeat fails to connect to the server for the first time (or every time) will the event WL.Events.WORKLIGHT_IS_DISCONNECTED be fired?
  - will the heartbeat continue to run/try once the WL.Events.WORKLIGHT_IS_DISCONNECTED was fired, or does it need to be reset/restarted manually?
  - if it does continue to run, will the event WL.Events.WORKLIGHT_IS_CONNECTED be fired once the heartbeat has it's first successful connection to the server again?

Answer (score 0):

The object that comes in on the onSuccess can be any (JSON) object you return from the back-end wrapped in an invocationResult together with an isSuccessful and errors attributes:

```
An object that contains the data that is returned by the invoked procedure, and the invocation status. Its format is as follows:
**invocationResult = {
    isSuccessful: Boolean,
    errors : "Error Message"
    // Procedure results go here
}**
Where:

isSuccessful – Contains true if the procedure invocation succeeded, false otherwise. If the invocation failed, the failure handler for the request is called.
errors – An optional array of strings containing error messages.
```

And for the failure:

```
The procedure was called but failed. In this case, the invocationResult property is added to the response received by the failure handler. This property has the same structure as the invocationResult property returned to the success handler, but the value of the isSuccessful attribute is false. For the structure of the invocationResult property, see invocationResult.
```

Comment: thank you for these details. would you, or someone have any details about the second part of the question - heartbeat and CONNECTED events/states.

Comment: I have not experience with it yet. If this answers part of your question please do mark this answer as useful.